# How do I configure Rails in production to use config.time_zone instead of the server time zone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In `config/application.rb`, I have set the time zone to EST:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

The production server has the `CST` time zone.  Consequently, all my date times are displaying the time in `CST` instead of `EST`.  The time is stored properly as UTC in the database.

```
EST: -0500
CST: -0600

Database in UTC: 18:15:00
Displayed in CST: 12:15:00
Want in EST: 13:15:00
```

The schema for the column `date_time` is:

```
t.datetime "date_time"
```

In the view, I call `date_time` like:

```
<%= Show.find(1).date_time.strftime('%H:%M') %>
```

How can I enforce all the time to display in `EST` across the web site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a bug in the way I was constructing the Time object.  The following construct will pick up the default zone `Central Time` of the server:

```
Time.new(2012, 1, 1, 11, 0)
```

I have to specify the time zone described in `config.time_zone` which picks up `EST` properly:

```
Time.new(2012, 1, 1, 11, 0, Time.zone.formatted_offset)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'` (it's actually the example line in `config/application.rb`) and use the localize helper:

```
<%= l Show.find(1).date_time, format: '%H:%M' %>
```

Get more information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Answer (score 0):

use `Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'`

UPDATE: try adding this to `application_controller.rb`

```
before_filter :set_timezone

def set_timezone
  Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
end
```

Comment: In which file should I initialise `Time.zone`?  When I output `Time.zone` in the html, it shows `EST` in production.  For some reason, when I display a column from the database, it shows the datetime as `CST`